# compilation error in gcc 4.2.2. but works in Xcode 6.4

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting this error message for all my function call and my it is initialised as below in the header file

```
void Initialisation(std::fstream &file, std::string name);
void Input(std::fstream &file, std::string name);
void Print(std::fstream &file, std::string name);
void Update(std::fstream &file, std::string name);
void Insert(std::fstream &file, std::string name);
void Delete(std::fstream &file, std::string name);
```

and called in the main file like this

```
Initialisation(dataFile, "hardware.dat");
```

`hardware.cpp: In function 'void Initialisation(std::fstream&, std::string)':
hardware.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
/packages/gcc/4.2.2/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.2/../../../../include/c++/4.2.2/fstream:778: note: candidates are: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`

Comment: GCC 4.4.2 isn't capable of a correct c++11 implementation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how do i fix it?

Comment: It *might* help if you told anyone what the error message is.

Comment: @molbdnilo hardware.cpp: In function 'void Initialisation(std::fstream&, std::string)':
hardware.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
/packages/gcc/4.2.2/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.2.2/../../../../include/c++/4.2.2/fstream:778: note: candidates are: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]

Comment: @Op-Zyra Use an up to date GCC version. Please post that stuff in your question, as you can spot it's not well readable in comments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ school server compiler :/

Comment: BTW what I can deduce from your error messages it's trivial to fix it, just pass `std::string::c_str()` for the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `std::string` as arguments to file operations was introduced in C++11, which is only supported fully from gcc 4.7 or so (this particular feature may well be available in older versions of gcc (since "new functionality provided by the compler/runtime is typically introduced "a bit at a time"), but 4.2.2 is bug fixes on 4.2.0, which was released in 2007, so it's about 8 years old by now.

Edit: As to the best of my understanding, XCode 6.4 uses a version of Clang 3.6, which should have full C++11 support. End Edit.

Edit2: You could use `-std=c++03` as an extra option on your XCode compiler, that would ensure that code that compiles in XCode also compiles in the gcc 4.2.2 compiler. End Edit2

Of course, if you don't NEED any other C++11 functionality, you can just replace `x.open(name)` with `x.open(name.c_str())`.

I would however have a chat with someone responsible for your schools choice of compiler and query as to whether it is an intentional decision to use a compiler that is so far out of date...

Comment: how do you use  -std=c++03 on XCode compiler?

Comment: I have not used the XCode IDE, so I'm not sure of the details, but somewhere you should be a "compiler options" set of settings, which either have an option for "standard to follow", or there should be a way to specify "additional options".